# Finding an open covering with no finite subcoverings for the set $(0,1) \times (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to find an open covering with no finite subcoverings for the set $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ in $\Re^2$.  I can find one for $(0,1)$, which is $(0, 1-\frac{1}{n})$ for $n>1$ as $(0,0)$ is not on $(0,1)$. Intuitively, $(0, 1-\frac{1}{n}) \times (0, 1-\frac{1}{n})$ would make sense to me (minus the $(0,0)$ that would be on it). Is this correct? If so, is there a better way to write it (something like $((0, 1-\frac{1}{n}), ...,( 1-\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}))$)? And if not, what is one such covering/how do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Intuitively, $(0, 1-\frac{1}{n}) \times (0, 1-\frac{1}{n})$ would make sense to me

It makes sense to me too.

> (minus the $(0,0)$ that would be on it).

Well, that problem could either be ignored (the empty set can be included in the cover without any issues), or we could say that $n$ starts at $2$.

> Is this correct?

Yes, it is. Good job. I would phrase an answer somewhere along these lines:

> The open cover $\left\{\left(0,1-\frac1n\right)\times \left(0, 1-\frac1n\right)\mid n\geq 2\right\}$ is an infinite cover of $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ with no finite subcover.

A covering like $\left\{\left(0,1-\frac1n\right)\times \left(0, 1\right)\mid n\geq 2\right\}$ would also work.

Comment: Thank you, if the empty set can be on the cover without problem then there is no issue, but I wonder why setting $n>1$ would help in the case of the product? $(a,b) \times  (c,d) = ((a,c),(a,d),(b,c),(b,d))$ right? In this case a and c would both be zero, regardless of the value of $n$.

Comment: @Jarmon No, $(a, b)\times(c, d)$ is a rectangle in the plane, with right and left boundaries at $a$ and $b$ along the $x$-axis, and the upper and lower boundaries at $c$ and $d$ along the $y$-axis. We wouldn't call this $((a, c), (a, d), (b, c), (b, d))$. (Yes, we use the same notation for the coordinates of a point in the plane and for intervals in the real line, and this is confusing. I have only used it for intervals in what I have written.)